# How to solve warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I checked my MySQL status using this command `sudo systemctl status MySQL` in the ubuntu server. I get this warning `mysqld[997]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer`. how to resolve this warning?

Comment: Probably another host has tried to contact your MySQL server and stopped.  In this case, there is nothing you can do.  The problem originates at the other end.  Is that warning frequent?

Comment: In Mysql status `sudo systemctl status MySQL`, it lists out 3 warnings only. I received warnings on that oct 10,12,13 dates. How to protect my Mysql? did you have any solution?

Comment: Has this problem occurred when we using a subdomain?